# Lenovo laptop takes long time to get to lenovo logo screen

Tags: boot, lenovo-laptop, clicking-sound

I have (Lenovo y50-70) laptop,
sometimes when I try to start the laptop, it takes long time to get to (lenovo logo screen)
(about 1-5 mins), and when that happens, the laptop makes (single click sound)
just before (lenovo logo screen) appears.
After the laptop boot up to Windows, it will work normally without any problem.

My question: why it takes long time to start, and what does the click sound mean?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Try starting it with a bootable USB key and check startup. Download Lenovo Diagnostics and run all the hardware tests.  Pay attention to the main drive.

Comment: I booted the laptop with Lenovo Diagnostics, run all the tests and all of them are passed. My drive brand is WD, so I used (WD Dashboard) tool to check it,  and no problem found, SMART status is (OK) and passed all the available tests.

Comment: If Windows 10, do a Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation link.